# empty rows when loading xml file into oracle table

Tags: xml

Please help me out loading an XML file into oracle table.
   Please help me out loading an XML file into oracle table.
   Please help me out loading an XML file into oracle table.

```
My XML file: textfile.xml

<ATB>
<CLAIMDATA oid="1">
    <Claimno>101</Claimno>
    <patname>John,Miller</patname>
    <payors>
        <payordata>
            <inscode>MCR</inscode>
            <insbal>100.66</insbal>
            <inspriority>1</inspriority>
        </payordata>
        <payordata>
            <inscode>BCBS</inscode>
            <insbal>200.20</insbal>
            <inspriority>2</inspriority>
        </payordata>
    </payors>
</CLAIMDATA>
<CLAIMDATA oid="2">
    <claimno>102</claimno>
    <patname>Louis,Phillipe</patname>
    <payors>
        <payordata>
            <inscode>TUFTS</inscode>
            <insbal> 1010.50</insbal>
            <inspriority>1</inspriority>
        </payordata>
    </payors>
</CLAIMDATA>
</ATB>

I have written the following query which gives me two empty rows with out any data.

WITH g AS (SELECT xmltype(bfilename('SAMP_XML_DIR','textfile.xml'), nls_charset_id('WE8ISO8859P1')) xmlcol1 FROM dual)
SELECT
extractValue(value(x),'ATB/CLAIMDATA/Claimno') claimno         
,extractValue(value(x),'ATB/CLAIMDATA/patname') patname  
,extractValue(value(x),'ATB/CLAIMDATA/payors/payordata/inscode[1]') ins1code
,extractValue(value(x),'ATB/CLAIMDATA/payors/payordata/insbal[1]') ins1bal
,extractValue(value(x),'ATB/CLAIMDATA/payors/payordata/inspriority[1]') ins1priority
,extractValue(value(x),'ATB/CLAIMDATA/payors/payordata/inscode[2]') ins2code
,extractValue(value(x),'ATB/CLAIMDATA/payors/payordata/insbal[2]') ins2bal
,extractValue(value(x),'ATB/CLAIMDATA/payors/payordata/inspriority[2]') ins2priority
FROM g,TABLE(XMLSequence(extract(g.xmlcol1,'ATB/CLAIMDATA'))) x;
```

Please let me know how can I get data

```
Thanks,
Sunil
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is create resource in XML DB Repository:

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY XMLDIR
AS
'FileFolderPath';`
```

--Create Resource

```
DECLARE
 res BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
 res := DBMS_XDB.createResource('/public/myfile.xml',
                             bfilename('XMLDIR', 'myfile.xml'),
                             nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'));
END;

SELECT x.clamino, x.patname, x.ins1code,
   x.ins1bal, x.ins1priority
FROM XMLTable('for $i in fn:doc("/public/myfile.xml")
             return $i'
            COLUMNS claimno  VARCHAR(10)  PATH 'ATB/CLAIMDATA/Claimno',
                    patname VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'ATB/CLAIMDATA/patname',

ins1code VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'ATB/CLAIMDATA/payors/payordata/inscode[1]',

ins1bal  VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'ATB/CLAIMDATA/payors/payordata/insbal[1]',

ins1priority  VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'ATB/CLAIMDATA/payors/payordata  /inspriority[1]') x;
```

...etc.

OR: Create XMLType table and load the file content in the table and use XMLQuery(XQuery) function

```
create table mytablename of xmltype;

insert into mytablename  VALUES
(XMLType( BFILENAME('XMLDIR','myfile.xml'), NLS_CHARSET_ID('AL32UTF8')   )); 

select XMLQUERY(for $i ora:view("mytablename")
              RETURNING CONTENT) from dual;
```